# Problemas com cURL no PHP 721

Tags: libcurl, php-7

Então, formatei meu **Notebook** e fui **reinstalar** o **Apache**

Instalei **Apache + PHP 721+ MySQL**.

Tudo funciona.

Fui tentar uma chamada com **cURL** e deu **erro**:

```
[Thu Apr 18 16:41:34.354241 2019] [php7:error] [pid 9344:tid 1212] [client ::1:50785] PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in D:\\Trabalhos\\host\\htdocs\\hotplateprensas.com.br\\teste.php:14\n
Stack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in D:\\Trabalhos\\host\\htdocs\\hotplateprensas.com.br\\teste.php on line 14
```

Procurei a linha do **cURL** no **php.ini** e descomentei:

```
extension=curl
```

**Não resolveu!**

Inserir uma linha a mais

```
extension=curl
extension=php_curl.dll
```

**também não resolveu:**

Obs.: a **dll**

```
php_curl.dll
```

está na pasta **ext** do **php721**

O que mais posso **fazer**?

Comment: O que o `phpinfo()` diz sobre a extensão? Você reiniciou o Apache depois de todas as alterações?

Comment: A única linha que tem sobre a CURL no phpinfo() é cURL Sterling Hughes. E sim, reinicie várias vezes. Inclusive reiniciei o windows também!